# How can I prevent my program from adding unwanted blank lines when reading and printing from text file - Python3

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I have code which will read a text file and print the lines from the file if they contain a particular word entered by the user (for example a name).

The issue is that if the program finds more than one line which matches the 'searched word', then the program will print the lines with an addition blank line between them. How do I get this program to print lines which match the search without a blank line separating each result?

```
line_number = 0

name = input("Who are you looking for? ")

with open('example.txt', "r") as a_file:
    for a_line in a_file:
        line_number += 1
        if name in a_line:
            print(line_number, a_line)

input()
```

Probably a very simple solution but I am stumped, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What "unwanted blank lines" are you seeing? Is it the newline generated by input() following the desired output?

Comment: just as a side note: instead of manually incrementing the line counter, use `enumerate()`, ie : `for line_number, a_line in enumerate(a_file):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `end` parameter in `print` function, like this

```
print(line_number, a_line, end="")
```

The default list of parameters to [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function looks like this,

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

Since `end` has `\n`, a new line will be inserted after every `print` call.

Comment: This doesn't have the desired effect. It closes the gap between line number and the data from the file for a particular line but doesn't remove the blank line generated between the separate print statements. Thank you for your time though.

Comment: @sw123456 Did you really try the change which I suggested? Because `end` is the only way you can fix this problem.

Comment: Now that I have tried end="", it works. Many thanks. You previously wrote sep="", which did not work. Thank you very much!

Comment: @sw123456 Sorry about that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 line_number = 0

name = input("Who are you looking for? ")

with open('example.txt', "r") as a_file:
    for a_line in a_file:
        line_number += 1
        if name in a_line:
            input(print("{}, {}".format(line_number, a_line)))
```

I suspect the "extra lines" you are getting are the result of using input(), which adds a new line following the print() of the desired output. Instead, you can just use the desired output at the display text for input().

Comment: Adding input instead of print causes an error. Thanks for your efforts though. Solution now found. I needed to add end="" to the print statement.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Corrected the error in my code, and the input statement now works.

Comment: Thanks again for your time. Your code doesn't answer the question but does allow me to have control as to when the next 'found' line appears. Many thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Each line that you read from the text file will still have the newline character at the end, an alternative to the accepted answer would to be to strip it away when you print:

```
line_number = 0

name = input("Who are you looking for? ")

with open('example.txt', "r") as a_file:
    for a_line in a_file:
        line_number += 1
        if name in a_line:
            print(line_number, a_line.rstrip())

input()
```

If you wanted to be more specific you could go with `.rstrip("\n")` instead, but I'm guessing you're not that interested in any whitespace (which is what rstrip does without arguments).